# Suppress Safari’s “You have entered text…” warning?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

[image: Are you sure you want to close this tab? You have entered text on “Stack Overflow”. If you close the tab, your changes will be lost. Do you want to close the tab anyway?]

Safari helpfully (?) prompts before closing a tab or window when text has been entered into an input.

There are some cases where, as a web developer, this isn’t desirable — for example, when the input is a live search where the user *has probably already gotten the results he’s looking for* when the window is closed, even though there’s still text in the field.

How can I let Safari know that text in a particular input doesn’t need its protection?

Comment: How do i get safari to do this? I figured that was JSs `onbeforeunload`. I just created a textarea and closed the tab without any warning at all. How do I recreate this?

Comment: you could clear the text fields in the onbeforeunload event. I don't know if that would work or not but it sounds like it might :)

Comment: Tried it with Google, and tried some other inputs i created... no go. Could you post your HTML and JS if any you have for this?

Comment: @Oscar: It looks like the input must be inside a form with a method. So, a minimal test case would look like `<form method="get"><input></form>`. However, I have no trouble reproducing this on Google and on Stack Overflow (I just type some letters and try to close the window). Is it possible that you've disabled this warning in your copy of Safari? There's no GUI for the preference, but there are utilities and command line examples of how to disable it.

Comment: What version of Safari are you on? Win or Mac? And no, I didn't disable anything through command line :\ let me know if @p--'s suggestion does or doesn't work and ill see if I cant reproduce this on my machine and come up with a solution

Comment: @Oscar Crazy! I'm using 5.0.4 on Mac OS. Yourself? Maybe it'd be worth trying as a different user… as far as I know, this alert is the normal behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got a solution to this problem, though it's unquestionably a hack (i.e. if Safari changes how this feature is implemented, it could stop working). Shown here with a touch of jQuery:

```
$('.unimportant').live('blur', function(){
    var olddisplay = this.style.display;
    this.style.display = 'none';
    this.clientLeft; // layout
    this.style.display = olddisplay;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92hdE/1/) (try typing in the "unimportant" field, click somewhere else on the page, then close the window).**

In short:

1. Hide the input
2. Trigger layout
3. Show the input

You can also change the value of the input, trigger layout, and change it back.

The one limitation here is that cleaning the input has to be done explicitly. In this case, it will be dirty until `blur`. This works well in my situation, and probably in many others, since the input will be protected from an accidental window close until something else on the page is manipulated (e.g. a link is clicked). You could choose to run this on `keyup` if you're willing to live with a flicker of the insertion point every time a key is pressed.

I'm open to cleaner solutions.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you are able to disable this warning for an entire page by having an `onbeforeunload` handler on `<body>` (even an empty one will do). For example, the following will not produce the warning:

```
<body onbeforeunload="">
    <form method="get"><input></form>
</body>
```

I'm not sure if this is the intended behaviour, or a bug.

Comment: This works great, +1. But, I don't want to kill the alert for the whole page, just unimportant search-type inputs. This could make it more likely for Safari users (who may be used to this alert) to lose data.

Answer (score 2):

I found what I think is a pretty good solution to this problem. When I use AJAX to submit the form then I want the warning to suppress. This is accomplished with onbeforeunload.

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(e){}
```

But after I submit I might make additional changes and so I want the warning to show again. To do this I added a keyup handler to a form element.

```
$('txtarea').onkeyup=dirty;
```

What dirty does is checks is the input field has changed if it has then I set  onbeforeunload to null.

```
function dirty(e){
 if (e.srcElement.value != e.srcElement.defaultValue){
  window.onbeforeunload=null;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Terry! The only problem with this solution is that it only supports one text input. Normally, if there is more than one input the warning gets displayed if any of them are dirty — but in this case, if any of them are clean, the warning won’t be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another solution  to prevent Safari from displaying the **"Are you sure you want to reload this page?"** dialog when textareas have changed their content.

It turns out that setting the value through Javascript clears Safari's `changed` state:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'textarea', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('').val(value);
});
```

Clearing the value first is important, directly setting it to the content it already is does not work.

**EDIT** Apparently setting `window.onbeforeunload` to an empty function still works, however `$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {})` does not.